# Get all defined variables in scope in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get all the variables that have been defined, i tried using the `global` object
but it seems to be missing the ones defined as `var token='44';` and only includes the ones defined as `token='44';`. What i am looking for idealy is something like the `get_defined_vars()` function of php. I need to access the variables because i need to stop the node process and then restart at the same point without having to recalculate all the variables, so i want to dump them somewhere and access them later.

Comment: That sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: Scope objects, other than Node's choice of enabling `global`, aren't made available in language. And, there are existing solutions for persistence -- files, databases, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes i understand the problems with this practise, but in this case i wont know that part of the code before hand and i wont be able to set a standart form of data. My only alternative is to serialize everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible within the language itself.

However:

1. If you have an access to the entire source code, you can use some library to get a list of global variables like this:

```
 var ast = require('uglify-js').parse(source)
 ast.figure_out_scope()
 console.log(ast.globals).map(function (node, name) {
     return name
 })
```

2. If you can connect to node.js/v8 debugger, you can get a list of local variables as well, see `_debugger.js` source code in node.js project.

Comment: Thanx thats a good one. I 'solved' this in an other way.. i used regex to replace variable definitions so they would show in the global object, and then i extracted them from that. I will choose your answer as the correct one :)

Comment: "It's impossible within the language itself", then you said it can be done with a library, kind of confising.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated

> I want to dump them somewhere and access them later.

It seems like you should work towards a database (as Jonathan mentioned in the comments), but if this is a one off thing you can use JSON files to store values. You can then `require` the JSON file back into your script and Node will handle the rest.

I wouldn't recommend this, but basically create a variable that will hold all the data / variables that you define. Some might call this a [God Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). Just make sure that before you exit the script, export the values to a JSON file. If you're worried about your application crashing, perform backups to that file more frequently.

Here is a demo you can play around with:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var globalData = loadData();

function loadData() {
    try { return require('./globals.json'); } catch(e) {}
    return {};
}

function dumpGlobalData(callback) {
    fs.writeFile(
        __dirname + '/globals.json', JSON.stringify(globalData), callback);
}

function randomToken() {
    globalData.token = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000, 10);
}

console.log('token was', globalData.token)
randomToken();
console.log('token is now', globalData.token)

dumpGlobalData(function(error) {
    process.exit(error ? 1 : 0);
});
```