# How to Check if a Class Exists in Node with a String

Tags: node.js, class, dynamic

Let's say I have this code:

```
Person = {};
var person = new Person();
```

Where Person is a class I defined in the file Person.js. Before invoking the code that executes above, I want to check to see if the Person class exists and if not I want to include it using require('./'+className). Doing this all dynamically, I only have a string to start with:

```
var className = 'Person';
```

How do I use my className string to identify if Person exists in Node JS? I know in the browser I can do this:

```
if(window[className])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I figured it out. In Node you can do:

```
var className = 'Person';
if(global[className])
```

Comment: You should not use globals like that. Just export the class in the module and then just require() the module. If it has already been required before, the class is cached so there is no real performance hit.

Comment: @Kirk It will only work if you didn't use the `var` keyword when declaring the class, which is very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible with Node.js to access the variables declared with `var`, and, as it is impossible to get a variable from a string in Javascript, you can not do what you want.

However, there should be another way to do what you want, if it is really a necessity, maybe you can use some **dirty** tricks like the one described here (it may not work given your project architecture):

[Get all defined variables in scope in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034469/get-all-defined-variables-in-scope-in-node-js)